# Query in Mongodb with openwhisk action

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, openwhisk

I am trying to run a find query on a mongo db and I want to do this in an openwhisk action. I am doing the same thing with nodejs and works perfectly, however in openwhisk I get no result. I suppose it has to do something with the asynchronous execution of javascript. However I am really new in this field and I am struggling to find a solution. Any suggestions? I have the working nodejs code.

```
function main(){
    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://172.29.91.113:27017/yelp', function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("yelp");
        var collection = dbo.collection("Review");
        var a = [];

        function queryCollection(collection, callback){
            collection.find({stars:5}).limit(100).toArray(function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } 
                a = result;
                callback();
                db.close();
            })
        } 

        queryCollection(collection, function(){
            return a;
        }); 
    })
}
```

Comment: There is an issues i see with your query.
You are trying to make a localhost database connection in Openwhisk which openwhisk may not have access to if it's not deployed locally.
Can you post your Openwhisk logs here.

Comment: It was locally but I have fixed this. Also I get no logs. I run openwhisk locally with vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your logic in a promise and return the promise in your Action

Comment: Could you help me a bit based on the code I have above?